# How to store two elements together in a stack Javascript calculator

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, stack, calculator

So I need to store elements in a Stack.
For instance, let's say I have to calculate 23 + 55. I want 23 in one index and 55 in one index. So it's not like `["2", "3", "+", "5", "5"]` but I want it as `["23", "+", "55"]`. I have to somehow store the first clicked number then get it when I have submitted my 2nd number.

```
<script>
  var stack = new Array();
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=button]");
  const length = buttons.length;


  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener("click", handle);
  }


  var prevop = '';

  function handle(event) {
    const value = event.target.value;

    stack.push(value);

    if (prevop == '=') {
      document.getElementById("textfield").value = "";
    }

    prevop = value;

    switch (value) {
      case "+":
        console.log("+ was clicked");
        document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
        break;
      case "-":
        console.log("- was clicked");
        document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
        break;
      case "*":
        console.log("* was clicked");
        document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
        break;
      case "/":
        console.log("/ was clicked");
        document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
        break;
      case "=":
        var tmp = eval(document.getElementById("textfield").value);
        document.getElementById("textfield").value += value + tmp;
        break;
      default:
        console.log("%s was clicked", value);
        document.getElementById("textfield").value += value;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Why `22` in `["22", "+", "55"]` instead if `23`

Comment: @brk obviously a Q typo

Comment: every time the user clicks a number button, add the number to an accumulating string (not the stack). Then, when the user presses an operator button, add the accumulated string to the stack along with the operator pressed.

Comment: You could always `eval(textfield.value)` if you absolutely trust user inputs (i.e: your input is not directly editable)

Comment: @NickParsons Can you please push me in a direction code-wise.